# Does redirection all invalid pages to index page affects seo?

Tags: google-search-console

I have a site, when I search for all pages in Google, I see many invalid pages. I checked google web master tools for removing urls. but it takes much time. I want to redirect all invalid pages individually to the index page.

Does this affect seo?

Comment: Better you redirect those pages to not found page instead of index page.

Comment: Great! thanks, but does this work also removes the page from google index?

Comment: Not.Google will consider that page as "not found" pages. If you want to prevent page from index , then you can put code : <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> in that page <head></head> section.

Comment: How about redirect them to a page like "/noindex.html" with that meta tag? Does this removes the page from google index?

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: If a page does not exist, you are always far better letting it 404 or even better yet, 410 if you can. Redirecting them to another page without a formal error will only keep the so called link alive and does not solve anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should redirect invalid pages to "not found" pages instead of index.

If you want to prevent google to index any specific page then put below code between section `<head> </head>`of that page :

```
 <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

If you want to prevent all other search engines to index any specific page then put below code between section `<head> </head>`of that page :

```
 <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Comment: How about redirect them to a page like "/noindex.html" with that meta tag? Does this removes the page from google index?

Comment: Yes you can do that and set meta as per my answer for noindex.html.